# Add column with values to object

Tags: powershell, object, hashtable

I need to compare variables for my apps and add a column called "Match" with a value Pass or Fail.
I already got the part of matching the values and print Pass/Fail in the screen, now i just need to add the values Pass or Fail to each of my variables to a new column in the object... this is where i don't know how to do.

This is where i have my current environment variables.
Run `$hash["deployment1"].spec.template.spec.containers.env`
And it lists:

```
name                                            value
----                                            -----
Build                                           001
Environment                                     DEV
OS                                              Windows
Log_Level                                       Information
```

This is where i have the expected values of variables.
Run `$variables.deployment1.image.env` and it lists:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Build                          001
Environment                    DEV
OS                             Windows
Log_Level                      Error
```

This is how i'm comparing the values

```
foreach($v in $hash["deployment1"].spec.template.spec.containers.env.name){
        Write-Host $v
        if ($hash["deployment1"].spec.template.spec.containers.env.where{$_.name -eq $v}.value -eq $variables.deployment1.image.env[$v]) {
            Write-Host "pass"
        }else{
            Write-Host "fail"
        }
    }
```

But instead of `Write-Host pass/fail` i'd like to add a column to `$hash["deployment1"].spec.template.spec.containers.env` with the expected value, like:

```
Name                           Value                           Match    
----                           -----                           ----
Build                          001                             Pass
Environment                    DEV                             Pass
OS                             Windows                         Pass
Log_Level                      Error                           Fail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done only through PSobject and not by Hashtable. Hashtable is only meant for key value pairs. Here is a sample for you. This can also be exported as a CSV.

```
$result = foreach($v in $hash["deployment1"].spec.template.spec.containers.env.name){
        Write-Host $v
        if ($hash["deployment1"].spec.template.spec.containers.env.where{$_.name -eq $v}.value -eq $variables.deployment1.image.env[$v]) {
            $output = "pass"
        }else{
            $output = "fail"
        }
        [pscustomobject]@{
        Name  = "Your Name value"
        Value = "Equivalent value"
        Match  = $output
    }
}
Write-Host $result
$result | Export-csv C:\temp\testresult.csv -NoTypeInformation
$result | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property name,value,match -Fragment -PreContent "<h3>Environment Variables</h3>"
```

Comment: How can i access these added values?

Comment: The thing is that i'm generating a html selecting the properties. `$hash[$data."Deployment Name"].spec.template.spec.containers.env | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property name,value -Fragment -PreContent "<h3>Environment Variables</h3>"` and i want to add a new property Match

Comment: Why you want to use ```$hash[$data."Deployment Name"].spec.template.spec.containers.env``` again? ``$result``` has already match in it. Try with ```$result | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Property name,value,match -Fragment -PreContent "<h3>Environment Variables</h3>" ```